# symfony2 reinstall vendors

Tags: symfony, propel

after execute `./bin/vendors install --reinstall`,
I have the error :

> 16384: The PropelBundle uses a new branching model, you should switch
>   to the 1.0 branch

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change version in `deps`:

```
[PropelBundle]
    git=git://github.com/propelorm/PropelBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Propel/PropelBundle
    version=origin/1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be good if you switch to composer for vendors as its much better way of updating vendors

have a look at at this here http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

Initially i was also reluctant to use it but once i made the move i never looked back